# Find a bijection\surjection between $A^{B}$ and $C^{D}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $A,B,C,D$ be nonempty sets.

A. Given $f:A\to C$, $g:B\to D$ are bijections, find a bijection between $A^{B}$ and $C^{D}$.

B. Given $f:A\to C$, $g:B\to D$ are injections, find an injection between $A^{B}$ and $C^{D}$.

I started with A, and I will write my attempt, but I don't see what the second question is for.

$Attempt:$ Let $K:B\to A$ be an arbitrary function. By definition, $K=\{(x,y)|x\in B, K(x)=y\in A\}$. Let us define $H:A^{B}\to C^{D}$: $H(K)=\{(g(x),f(y)),\forall (x,y)\in K\}$. It is easy to check that this is a well defined function from $D$ to $C$. Suppose there are two functions $K_1,K_2: B \to A$, then  $H(K_1)=H( K_2)$ $\Rightarrow$ for every $(g(x_1),f(y_1))\in H(K_1)$ there exists $(g(x_2),f(y_2))\in H(K_2)$ such that $(g(x_1),f(y_1))=(g(x_2),f(y_2))$. By injectivity of $f$ and $g$ we get that for every such a couple, $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$. Therefore $K_1=K_2$ and $H$ is injective.

**Surjectivity**: Let $S:D \to C$ be a function. Then $S=\{(a,b)|a\in D, S(a)=b\in C\}$. $f$ and $g$ are surjective and therefore for every $(a,b)\in S$ we can find $x_1\in B$, $x_2\in A$ such that $(g(x_1),f(x_2))=(a,b)$. Therefore $H$ is surjective.

Now, I don't understand why the other question exists. It makes me feel like there is something wrong with what I am doing, because as far as I know, I already proved that at the beginning. I could really use some enlightenment on the issue.

Comment: If would be simpler to write $$H(K) = g^{-1}\circ K \circ f$$ which is your construction in compacter form. This form also hints at what goes wrong if you try to apply this reasoning to (b) without change -- if $g$ is only injective but not surjective, then $g^{-1}$ does not exist. If you try to apply your element-by-element definition of $H(K)$ you will find that it is not defined at every element of $D$ unless $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh I see
Now it made me question my proof of A. How is it to your opinion?

Comment: x @donna: Your idea is the right one, but your phrasing of it is somewhat heavy to read (in a trees-rather-than-forest sort of way), and in the proof of surjectivity you stop before you've actually constructed an element of $A^B$ that maps to $S$. I think it would be worth the trouble to rewrite it in terms of function composition rather than working with individual elements of $B\times A$ and $D\times C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b), use the fact that $f$ is an injection if and only if it has a *retraction*, i.e. there exists a map $r\colon C\rightarrow A$ such that $ r\circ f=1_A$. Similarly, $g$ has a retraction $s\colon D\rightarrow B$. Retractions are not unique, except if the injection is indeed a bijection. Let's fix retractions of $f$  and $g$. Define a map  $\varphi\colon A^B \rightarrow C^D$ by
$$\varphi(K)=f\circ K\circ r.$$
This map is injective: if $\varphi(K)=\varphi(K')$, i.e. if $\,f\circ K\circ r=f\circ K'\circ r$, then
\begin{align*}s\circ(f\circ K\circ r)= s\circ(f\circ K'\circ r)&\iff (s\circ f)\circ( K\circ r)=  (s\circ f)\circ( K'\circ r)\\
&\iff K\circ r=K'\circ r\qquad\mathrm{since}\quad s\circ f=1_A
\end{align*}
Now a retraction is *surjective*, so $\,K\circ r=K'\circ r\Rightarrow K=K'$.